# VxWorks 6.9 memInfoGet returns -1?

Tags: vxworks

I`m working on vxWorks 6.9 and trying to get some numbers on the heap allocation with the function below

```
void DebugGetMemUsage(PART_ID partId)
```

{

```
MEM_PART_STATS   partStats;
char text[30] = {0};


if(memPartInfoGet(partId,&partStats) == OK)
{
    sprintf(text,"%u %u %u %u %u %u"
                                ,partStats.maxBlockSizeFree,
                                partStats.maxBytesAlloc,
                                partStats.numBlocksAlloc,
                                partStats.numBlocksFree,
                                partStats.numBytesAlloc,
                                partStats.numBytesFree);

    Send_Debug(0,text);

}
else
{
    Send_Debug(0,"memPartInfoGet Error");       
}
```

}

and this is how I call it

```
DebugGetMemUsage(memSysPartId);
```

Every time I call DebugGetMemUsage I receive

```
memPartInfoGet Error
```

I have also tried

```
int res = memInfoGet(&partStats);
sprintf(text,"memInfoGet result : %d",res);
DCI_Debug(0,text);
```

and received -1 on the console for the return value of memInfoGet

Any idea what I`m doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I see that you are using the memInfoGet in wrong way, no pool has been specified. Attaching our sample for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands to verify memSysPartId.

```
-> my_buffer = malloc(64)
-> memset (my_buffer,0,64)
-> memPartInfoGet memSysPartId,my_buffer
-> d my_buffer,64,4
NOTE: memory values are displayed in hexadecimal.
0x101a19c0:           0278c228 00000103 026affd0  *    ( x ......j.*
0x101a19d0:  09f8d078 00004d32 0a04d7e4 00000000  *x...2M..........*
```

0x026affd0 in the memory dump is maxBlockSizeFree.